# Set statement descriptor dynamically in Stripe

Tags: java, stripe-payments

In Stripe, you can define a static statement descriptor in the Dashboard that will appear as a prefix of all transaction, e.g.:

> MYCOMPANY

When creating a new payment manually from the Dashboard, it's possible to define the full statement descriptor that will appear on the payment statement, e.g.:

> TRAVEL TO MADRID BY MYCOMPANY

But while using the Stripe API in Java the statement descriptor parameter is just added to the prefix defined in the dashboard:

```
        ChargeCreateParams ccp = ChargeCreateParams.builder()
            .setSource(create().getId())
            .setAmount(new Long(1300))
            .setCurrency("eur")
            .setStatementDescriptor("TRAVEL TO MADRID BY MYCOMPANY")
            .build();
```

Result of the Statement descriptor in Stripe is:

> MYCOMPANY* TRAVEL TO

Stripe truncates the statement descriptor from the API to 10 characters and add it to statement descriptor defined in the dashboard

Is it possible the define the full statement descriptor through the API to get the same behaviour as with the manual payment?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the API documentation says you can have a maximum of 22 characters.
But apparently there is another way to create a Charge (if this is your goal).

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc";

// `source` is obtained with Stripe.js; see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/collecting/web#create-token
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("amount", 2000);
params.put("currency", "usd");
params.put("source", "tok_visa");
params.put(
  "description",
  "Charge for jenny.rosen@example.com"
);

Charge charge = Charge.create(params);
```

I hope this answer helped you.

**Sources** 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create 
https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.stripe/stripe-java/14.4.1/com/stripe/param/ChargeCaptureParams.Builder.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The 22 characters limitation is not a problem. I'd like to define the "complete statement descriptor" as stated in the doc, and not a descriptor added to the prefix: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-statement_descriptor